# Heavy tailed and Normal distribution in same plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, statistics

I want to display Heavy Tailed (Levy) distribution with Gaussian (in same plot).

I did it for Gauss:

```
from pylab import plot, show, grid, axis, xlabel, ylabel, title, rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math
mu = 0                         
variance = 1
sigma = math.sqrt(variance)     
plt_z = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)

1./(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma)*np.exp(-0.5 * (1./sigma*(x - mu))**2)
plt.plot(plt_z, mlab.normpdf(plt_z, mu, sigma))
plt.show()
```

and I get[image]

Now I want to add Levy distribution in that plot, but not getting it right. I tried with `scipy.stats.levy` and manually adding equation:

```
1./(x * np.sqrt(2*np.pi*x)) * np.exp(-1/(2*x))
```

but not getting correct plot

**This is what i want to get**:
[image]

just heavy tailed Levy distribution in same plot

Comment: Did you try putting `plt.show()` after the two `plt.plot()`?

Comment: i get 2 plots, but second one is all but heavy tailed distribution for some rason. It looks like 2 perpendicular lines only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to plot Levy stable distribution with alpha parameter `1` in the same plot with normal distribution using [PyLevy](https://github.com/josemiotto/pylevy) package.

Here's the code if someone is struggling with this:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import levy


random_sample = levy.random(1.0, 0, 0, 1, shape=200)


parameters = norm.fit(random_sample)

x = np.linspace(-4,4,100)

# Generate the pdf (fitted distribution)
fitted_pdf = norm.pdf(x)

#Generate Levy fitted distribution
parameters2 = levy.fit_levy(random_sample)
levy_fitted = levy.levy(x, *parameters2[:4])

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.plot(x,fitted_pdf,"blue",label="Gauss Fot", linewidth=2)
plt.plot(x, levy_fitted, "red", label="Levy Fit", linewidth=2)
plt.legend()

# show plots
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
from pylab import plot, show, grid, axis, xlabel, ylabel, title, rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math
mu = 0                         
variance = 1
sigma = math.sqrt(variance)     
plt_z = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)

1./(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma)*np.exp(-0.5 * (1./sigma*(x - mu))**2)
plt.plot(plt_z, mlab.normpdf(plt_z, mu, sigma)) #plotting the Gauss curve

mask_positive_x = plt_z > 0
plt_z = plt_z[mask_positive_x]
plt.plot(plt_z, 1./(plt_z * np.sqrt(2*np.pi*plt_z)) * np.exp(-1/(2*plt_z))) #plotting the Levy curve
plt.show()
```

The Levy distribution is only defined for positive x: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_distribution

If you absolutely want the Levy curve on both sides of the real line:

```
from pylab import plot, show, grid, axis, xlabel, ylabel, title, rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math
mu = 0                         
variance = 1
sigma = math.sqrt(variance)     
plt_z = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)

1./(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma)*np.exp(-0.5 * (1./sigma*(x - mu))**2)
plt.plot(plt_z, mlab.normpdf(plt_z, mu, sigma)) #plotting the Gauss curve

plt.plot(plt_z, 1./(np.abs(plt_z) * np.sqrt(2*np.pi*np.abs(plt_z))) * np.exp(-1/(2*np.abs(plt_z)))) #plotting the Levy curve
plt.show()
```

Comment: It looks good on one side, with an error: /Users/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:13: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  del sys.path[0]

Comment: I made an edit after noticing that the Levy formula is ill-defined for `x<0` and checking on wikipedia that its support must be the positive real line.

Comment: It should be `plt_z = plt_z[mask_positive_x]`

Comment: Both your solutions result in the same plot.

Comment: @AnkitGupta It should not be the first one plots the Levy curve only for positive `x` the second one will plot it for both positive and negative. The first one is a support restriction of the second one.

Comment: Well, `plt_z = np.abs( plt_z)` results in all positive values of `plt_z` which includes each value twice. So basically there is no negative `z` value in `plt_z`. You can print it to see for yourself. So basically in the second answer, you are just plotting everything twice on the positive x axis.

Comment: Even now it's not correct. I would suggest you to please look at your resulting plot before you post edits. There is a clear discontinuity near the origin. The Levy distribution is zero in the limit x tending to 0. So just mirroring the positive x-axis curve along the y-axis won't result in what OP wants. You can't get a maxima at `plt_z=0` with what you are doing.

Comment: You have minimum at x=0 instead of maximum